# How can I make a Last Year calculations from custom date - compare date table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables:

SalesTable with columns sale and date

DatesTable with columns date and comparedate

In the SalesTable all my sale is listed with a date.

In the DatesTable I define what other date a given date should be compared to.
Say fx that I for some reason would like to compare 31/12-2021 to 1/12/2020. Then In my Dates table I would have date= 31/12-2021 and comparedate=1/12/2020

DatesTable is manually filled out with dates.
Dates are unique and all dates are pressent.

How can I use this table to find last years sale for at given date using the comparedate?

I know howto make at weekday to weekday caclulation, but here there are no system for how the  dates relates to comparedates.

Any hint is very much appreciated.
BR Kresten

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to grab the compare date value and pass that to a filter in your measure:

note: the chart/table needs to use the date from the date table as a slicer

```
Total Sales = SUM(SalesTable[Sales])

Compare Sales = 
  VAR compareDate = SELECTEDVALUE(DatesTable[CompareDate])
  RETURN CALCULATE([Total Sales], 
      DatesTable[Date] = compareDate
    )
```

Comment: I dont get any data out.
Would this require any relations between the two tables ?

Comment: you need an active relationship between the date table - date and the sales table - date

Comment: I stille can't make this work. I have a Many to one relation between the tho dates collumns going from sales table to DatesTable.
This is my messure
    Compare Sales = 
      VAR compareDate = SELECTEDVALUE('BiCalendarUser'[CompareWithDate])
      RETURN CALCULATE([Mål_NetAmount],
          ALL('InvoiceLines'[Date]),
          'InvoiceLines'[Date] = compareDate
        )

Comment: Hi @Kresten please see edited answer (including note)